# How to get Point value with python-pptx to edit format on each point based on it's value

Tags: python, powerpoint

If I run the following code

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('test3.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_chart:
            continue
        chart = shape.chart
        for series in chart.series:
            print(series.values)
```

on a presentation that only includes the pictured chart

[image: Example chart]

I will get the following output

```
(0.1, 0.4, 0.7)
(0.2, 0.5, 0.8)
(0.3, 0.6, 0.9)
```

Being that A, B, and C are the 3 Series

How would I go about doing something similar with each Point within the chart? The following code doesn't work

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('test3.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_chart:
            continue
        chart = shape.chart
        for series in chart.series:
            for point in series.points:
                print(point.values)
```

and I'm finding in the documentation that Points doesn't store value, only the formats.

My ultimate goal is to be able to edit the formatting of each point individually based on it's value. e.g. if point value >= 50% -> color green; if < 50% -> color red etc...

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate attributes that are found in different places in the XML, which explains why `Point` does not have a `.value` property.

But they will correspond in number, so there's no problem with putting them together. The built-in `zip()` function is just for this sort of thing:

```
for point, value in zip(series.points, series.values):
    do_whatever_with(point, value)
```